# How to kill application using c#

Tags: c#, kill

Here's my situation: I'm using c# and opening multiple pdf files. When watching the `taskmanager`, I see that each new file I open shows in the applications tab, while there is only 2 `adobe32` processes. If I do a `getprocesses` by name, I see the two processes and if I drill down into them, I am able to identify one of the pdf's I have opened by the mainwindow title name, but I am unable to find the other. My goal is to be able to terminate whichever window I choose without having to close both of them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just save the handle to the process when you open the file, and use that same handle later to close the process.

Comment: Process.Id can be used to distinguish between them.

Comment: Going off or the previous comments the problem almost solved. It seems both of the open adobe Reader windows have the same processID but different handle id's. Soon as I figure out how to close the handle I think that will be it.

Comment: ok..Is there a way to close a handle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use P-Invoke with your window handle IDs:

CloseWindow:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.closewindow

Or DestroyWindow:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/DestroyWindow.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it would depend if there are requirements on how you can open the PDF file. Without seeing what you are doing I can only make assumptions at this point. Anyways this method doesn't involve using p-invoke to trash the windows that are open.

If you call AcroRd32.exe use the /n command line switch and pass the path of the PDF file then it will open a new instance of AcroRd32.exe for each PDF file that you open. There could potentially be a number of ways to then close a certain PDF document.

Here is one simple method that will open the two files, since you still have access to the pdfProcess1 you can kill it:

```
Process pdfProcess1 = new Process();
pdfProcess1.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("AcroRd32.exe", "/n" + Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "SomePDFDoc1.pdf"));
pdfProcess1.Start();

Process pdfProcess2 = new Process();
pdfProcess2.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("AcroRd32.exe", "/n" + Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "SomePDFDoc2.pdf"));
pdfProcess2.Start();

pdfProcess1.Kill();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, This should work perfectly for what I'm trying to do.